# C#.net Radiobuttonlist need

Tags: c#

I have radiobuttonlist and I have the table field is (cityname,hotalname,cost) and I stored the many city names like "chennai,mumbai,delhi,chennai,mumbai" and I connect the database and execute using this query keyword "distinct", it will show like:

```
() chennai
() delhi
() mumbai
```

Now if I select the first option chennai means it should display only the details of chennai (cityname,hotalname,cost) in grid view, and if I select the second option mumbai means it should display only the details of mumbai (cityname,hotalname,cost) in grid view,
if I select the  third option delhi means it should display only the details of delhi (cityname,hotalname,cost) in grid view, etc.

Using C#.net

Comment: What is your question? And what platform - ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight?

Comment: Are you having a particular issue with this?  Or are you delivering requirements to us?

Answer (score 0):

You need to react to an event of your RadioButtonList, so you should write a code similar to this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myRadioButtonList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(rb_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

void rb_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myGridView.DataSource = SomeClass.GetDetails(myRadioButtonList.SelectedValue);
    myGridView.DataBind();
}
```

Or something like that, depends on your needs. Hope you get the idea.